# Do red "destructive" buttons hurt accessibility?

Tags: accessibility, color, delete, color-blindness

My organization currently uses red buttons for destructive actions, e.g. Delete A or Revoke X.

I'm wondering if this hurts accessibility, given that our primary CTA buttons are blue and our secondary buttons are gray. I believe colorblind users can make that distinction.

Is there a best practices guide on destruction patterns? One that takes into account accessibility?

Comment: They are not good for users' experience i guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>**Disclaimer:** The software I produce is not required to be WCAG compliant, so I cannot speak to any official requirements. However, my dad is colorblind, so there's that...</sup>

One of the most important accessibility considerations for colorblindness is that **meaning is not communicated through color alone**.

A good use of color can help to speed up processing by providing subconscious hints (e.g. red is destructive, light blue is informative, green is successful, etc.), but it shouldn't be relied upon exclusively to communicate ideas.

A simple test to determine if an item is relying too much on color is to simply remove the color and evaluate if it still communicates the same message to the user. You can search online for a colorblind simulator that will take an image or sometimes a URL and render it in various ways to simulate different colorblindness conditions.

This means that your concern should be confirming that your labeling and iconography is descriptive and consistent. As long as your text-to-background contrast is acceptable, that should be sufficient.

Comment: If the OP is using text labels on their buttons, then this would meet the accessibility requirement, i.e. colour would be used along with a text label to communicate meaning. Great advice to either greyscale your page or use a colour blindness simulator.

Comment: To add to your suggestion about colorblind simulators. There are multiple Chrome extensions that do for various types of colorblindness. I personally enjoy "Colorblinding"